# Do I need to have a certain amount of money with me to travel in the US?

Tags: air-travel, usa

If I am a visitor from another country traveling with visa and I am traveling from one US city to another do I need a certain amount of travel money on me to do so?

Comment: By visa do you mean a credit card ?

Comment: By money do you mean cash (vs. credit card)?

Answer (score 5):

Obviously you will need money to pay for things, but no one will check that you have some minimum amount of money before admitting you to the city. There are no internal "border" controls within the continental United States.